# PHP - How can I store variable states?

Tags: php

I'm learning php, and I'm having a hard time finding answers to this. How do I keep a variable after I've submitted a form that has to call the page again? (Weird wording?) I am trying to keep $num_to_guess and $num_tries. I'm following instructions I found to include $num_tries as a hidden input in the html block, but it still does not increment it after I submit the form.

**How do I save $num_to_guess AND $num_tries after submission?**

---

```
<?php
  if ( !isset ( $num_tries ) )
  {
    $num_to_guess = rand(1, 100);
  }
  $num_tries = ( isset ( $_POST['num_tries'] ) ) ? $num_tries + 1 : 0;
  if ( !isset ( $_POST['guess'] ) ) {
    $message = "Welcome to the guessing machine!";
  } elseif ( !is_numeric ( $_POST['guess'] ) ) {
    $message = "I don't understand that response...";
  } elseif ( $_POST['guess'] == $num_to_guess ) {
    $message = "Well done! That is the number!";
  } elseif ( $_POST['guess'] < $num_to_guess ) {
    $message = $_POST['guess'] . " is too small!";
  } elseif ( $_POST['guess'] > $num_to_guess ) {
    $message = $_POST['guess'] . " is too big!";
  } else {
    $message = "I am terribly confused...";
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A PHP Number Guessing Script</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>The Guessing Game</h2>
  <p>1-100<br/>
    Guess number: <?php echo $num_tries ?></p>
  <h3><?php echo $message; echo $num_to_guess?></h3>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <p><label for="guess">Type your guess here:</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="num_tries" value="<?php echo $num_tries; ?>"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to set these to a session variable like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['guess'] = $num_to_guess;
$_SESSION['tries'] = $num_tries;
```

Then to access them you would do...

```
session_start();
$guess = $_SESSION['guess'];
$tries = $_SESSION['tries'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're asking for, then you are looking for $_SESSION! $_SESSION allows you to store variables, during a user's session on a website. Sessions are typically set to twenty minutes. The global $_SESION variable is basically an associative array of key=>values you want to keep stored for a user. This should help you out.

Take a look [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) for more information. Give it a read. It gives you a good rundown on how sessions work, as well as some examples.

Comment: Apart from $_session/Cookies, you have the option of cache/localstorage using JS if you use good client app frameworks like AngularJS or EmberJS. The server control on these will however be lesser. But if you are wanting to change/store it in the server or store the variables in the server then sessions or log files or db (based on amount of data) might be your best bet. There are many ways you can approach this. All the best. Let us know if you implemented this correctly or need more help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sessions.

In the first line of your code, add **session_start**, then you can use the super global **$_SESSION** to store and retrieve data.

The first request of the session will have to initialize the variables, subsequent requests may read or update them.

```
<?php

// Start the session before sending any output to the browser
// This sets a cookie value that identifies the session
session_start();

// This ensures that the number to guess is only set once
if (!isset($_SESSION['number_to_guess'])) {
    $number_to_guess = $_SESSION['number_to_guess'] = rand(0,100);
}

// This ensures the number of tries is properly initialized
if (!isset($_SESSION['guesses'])) {
    $_SESSION['guesses'] = 0;
} else {
    // Increment guesses
    $_SESSION['guesses']++;
}
```